# XSL transformation generating output from other nodes

Tags: xml, formatting, xslt

I have the following XSL template (I omitted the template for Organization, let me know if it's necessary):

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">     
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="SOAP-ENV:Body/*[local-name()='Publisher']">
    <html>      
        <xsl:call-template name="body" />
    </html>     
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="body">
    <BODY>
        <br/>
        <center>
            <font face="arial" size="2">
                <b>Publisher <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Organization']/*[local-name()='PublisherData']/*[local-name()='PublisherName']"/>
                </b>
            </font>
        </center>
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='Organization']"/>
    </BODY>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The previous template generates the output I want, it's generating the  tags containing  the output generated by the "body" template. The issue I'm having is that before the opening  tag I'm getting text output from a previous node. Not sure why this is happening since I'm not selecting these other nodes. For example:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <n1>abc</n1>
                <n2>def</n2>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <Publisher>
                          <!--Child nodes here -->
                    </Publisher>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Given the previous sample XML fragment, my output would contain what I would expect of formatting the Publisher element, but I'm also getting the text nodes of the children of the SOAP-ENV:Header node.

I only want to transform the contents of the Publisher element, but in the output I'll get:

```
abc
def
//Expected output transforming Publisher goes here
```

My question is, why abc and def are being selected?

Comment: You'll have to post the entire XSL for us to figure out where the other text is coming from. Also, post a sample of XML large enough to reproduce the problem (and no larger!). Finally, post the resulting XML.

Comment: @Abel: I recommend you get rid of all the `*[local-name() = ...]` stuff. It bloats your XSL and serves no purpose. `<xsl:value-of select="Organization/PublisherData/PublisherName"/>` is a lot nicer, isn't it?

Comment: @Tomalak: you're right given the previous example, I just suppressed the namespaces and prefixes (I have a bunch of them) for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is being generated because of the [built in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) which:

- copy text nodes to output
- apply templates to elements

The relevant section of the XSLT 1.0 Recommendation is included below.

You may just want a do nothing template for the SOAP-ENV:Header.

```
<xsl:template match="SOAP-ENV:Header">
</xsl:template>
```

Some of the elements in your source document are not in a namespace. In an XPath expression, elements that do not have a namespace may be referred to by their literal local name. You only need to use of `local-name()` if you do not know the namespace for an element.

Here is a modified version of your stylesheet. It starts with a template to match `/` and then explicitly select the nodes we want.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>      
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SOAP-ENV:Body/Publisher" />
        </html>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Publisher">
        <body>
            <br/>
            <center>
                <font face="arial" size="2">
                    <b>
                        <xsl:text>Publisher </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Organization/PublisherData/PublisherName"/>
                    </b>
                </font>
            </center>
            <br/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Organization"/>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Built-in Template Rules**

> There is a built-in template rule to
>   allow recursive processing to continue
>   in the absence of a successful pattern
>   match by an explicit template rule in
>   the stylesheet. This template rule
>   applies to both element nodes and the
>   root node. The following shows the
>   equivalent of the built-in template
>   rule:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/">
>   <xsl:apply-templates/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule
>   for each mode, which allows recursive
>   processing to continue in the same
>   mode in the absence of a successful
>   pattern match by an explicit template
>   rule in the stylesheet. This template
>   rule applies to both element nodes and
>   the root node. The following shows the
>   equivalent of the built-in template
>   rule for mode m.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/" mode="m">
>   <xsl:apply-templates mode="m"/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule
>   for text and attribute nodes that
>   copies text through:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
>   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for
>   processing instructions and comments
>   is to do nothing.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for
>   namespace nodes is also to do nothing.
>   There is no pattern that can match a
>   namespace node; so, the built-in
>   template rule is the only template
>   rule that is applied for namespace
>   nodes.
>
> The built-in template rules are
>   treated as if they were imported
>   implicitly before the stylesheet and
>   so have lower import precedence than
>   all other template rules. Thus, the
>   author can override a built-in
>   template rule by including an explicit
>   template rule.

Comment: @Lachlan: I suggest you tell him why his XSL didn't work, not just show him how to make it work.

Comment: Great! This worked, but I don't get it, why using a nothing template for SOAP-ENV:Header solved the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Lachlan: I fail to see the usefulness of `local-name()` in this context.

Comment: @Tomalak; you're right given the previous example, I just suppressed the namespaces and prefixes (I have a bunch of them) for clarity.